# i can't upload any files in this code online but locally it works

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code and it working good locally in my local host . but when I try to open it online it doesn't work .just have an error in image . and by the way my connection file is right i cheeked it . and i have 755 permission on the folder of all web  .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Fatih</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tiny/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<form action="addarticle.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Please choose a file: <input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>

  title : <input type="text" class="name" name="name" value=""></br>
  auther : <input type="text" class="name" name="auther" value=""></br>
  date : <input type="text" class="name" name="date" value=""></br>
      text :          <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
                    </textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="botton" value="insert" name="go"><br>

</form> 


<?
    include '../include/config.php';
?>





<?php
    if ($_POST['go']){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $auther = $_POST['auther'];
    $text = $_POST['elm1'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $namei = $_POST['namei'];

$target_dir = "../images/article/";
$target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk=1;

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_dir . $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"])) {


    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($uploadFile_size > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Only GIF files allowed
if (!($uploadFile_type == "image/jpeg")) {
    echo "Sorry, only GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $namei = basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);

          $add = mysql_query("insert into article values ('','$name','$auther','$text','$date','$namei')");






    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}




echo " 
    <div class='imagest'>
    this is mine 
    <img class='imagest'src='../images/article/$namei'> 
    </div>
    ";

    }




    }


?>
```

Comment: What error it is giving?

Comment: echo "Sorry, only GIF files are allowed.";

Comment: Try with a GIF files.  If it works, then it's a configuration problem at either the php.ini file on the web server or on the web server itself that prohibits everything but the uploading of GIF files.  If it's in the php.ini file, then you can possibly resolve the issue by adding the suffixes of the other types of files that you want to upload but if it's at the server level, then possibly you cannot add your own list of suffixes.  (This restriction is a security measure.)

Comment: i have the same error .

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!($uploadFile_type == "image/gif")) {
    echo "Sorry, only GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: i tyr to upload jpg file . i don't want gif

Comment: Then the message should be "Sorry, only JPG files are allowed"

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your code :

```
if (!($uploadFile_type == "image/jpeg")) {
    echo "Sorry, only GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Can you check if $_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"] is actually returning 'image/jpeg' ?

Comment: actually doesn't returning 'image/jpeg'

Comment: Ok, then check what type is it returning. Is that 'image/pjpeg' or something else ? If so, create an array of all valid mime types and then check the uploaded file's mime type against it using in_array function. Remember that different browsers can return different mime types, so test your code on all common (popular) browsers.  This may also be useful : http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php